# Toggle Between Classes To Slide In Content On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys looking for some assistance as the heat appears to be melting my brain. I'm having a stupid problem and in once of those situations where i should probably take a break and come back to this but hey.

Basically all i want to do is I add/removeClasses when the user clicks on the primary About Me button and then close with the .close class button.

For some reason I just can't see what I've dont wrong lol. I know I need jquery for this to add/removeClass. I also know I need to setup a new class to add the active state of the overlay and set a width to 100%. I'm just not having much joy at the moment. I have it working fine on hover but that isnt adequate for mobile so I need an onClick event for this. Came up with this so far. I know im close, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Jquery Code

```
//open on  click
$(".slideIn").click(function(){
   $(".overlay").addClass('.overlay-active');
}); 

//close on x button click
$(".close").click(function(){
   $(".overlay").removeClass('.overlay-active');
});
```

HTML CODE

```
 <section class="intro" role="region">
        <div class="split-screen row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 left">
            <a class="btn-btn-primary slideIn" style="color:#fff;" title="link to landing page task" href="#"><h2>About Me</h2></a>

            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">
                    <figure class="col-lg-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/nick_avatar.png" ></figure>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>

                        <h3>Nick</h3>
                        <p>some text| some text | some text</p>
                        <q>a bit more text for us to read here, why not</q>
                        <br/><br/>
                        <h3>Lets Connect</h3>
                        <div class="social row">
                            <a href="#" class="tel" title="Call Me" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" role="link"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            <a href="#" class="mail" title="E-mail Me" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" role="link"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <a target="_blank" href="#" alt="Connect With Me On Twitter" title="Connect With Me On Twitter" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" role="link"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <a target="_blank" href="#" alt="Connect With Me On LinkedIn" title="Connect With Me On LinkedIn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" role="link"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <a target="_blank href="#" alt="Connect With Me On CodePen" title="Connect With Me On CodePen" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" role="link"><i class="fa fa-codepen fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <a target="_blank" href="#" alt="Connect With Me On GitHub" title="Connect With Me On GitHub" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" role="link"><i class="fa fa-github fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 right">
            <a class="btn-btn-primary" title="link to landing page task" href="#"><h2>To The Task</h2></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

CSS CODE

```
   html{
      height:100%
    }
    body{
      height:100%;
    }

    .intro{
      height:100%
    }

    .split-screen{height:100%;}

    .left{
      position: relative;
      display : flex;
      justify-content : center;
      align-items : center;
      background-color:#009dcc;
      height : 100%;
      color : #FFF;

    }
    .right{
      display : flex;
      justify-content : center;
      align-items : center;
      background-color:#FFF;
      height : 100%;
      color : #000000;
    }
    @media (max-width: 1200px) { 
      .left{
        height:50%
      }
      .right{
        height:50%
      }
    }

    .fa{margin:15px;}


    .overlay {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #008CBA;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: .5s ease;
    }

    .overlay-active {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .fa{color:#ffffff;}
    .fa:hover{color:#fac600;}

    .text {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width:84%;
      height:50%;
      white-space: nowrap; 
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    figure{padding:10px;}
    figure img{
        border:3px solid #fff;
        border-radius:50%;
    }
    .social{border-top: 2px solid #fff;}

    @media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    figure{display:none;}
    .text{padding:5px; height:67%;}
    }
    @media all and (max-width: 468px) {
    p,q{font-size:12px;}    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your functions, remove the `.` from the class name in `addClass()` and `removeClass()`. With it you're actually adding a class called `.overlay-active` which includes the `.`.

Also, worth noting, you do not **need** jQuery to add or remove a class. Remember, jQuery is *just javascript*.